Bound on success Probability for Regev's factoring algorithm
Theorem 4.1 in Regev's paper talks about a theorem due to Pomerance as follows:

Theorem 4.1: Suppose G is a finite abelian group with minimal number of generators $r$. Then, when choosing elements from $G$ independently and uniformly, the expected number of elements needed to generate G is less than r + σ, where σ = 2.118456563....

Then, Corollary 4.2 is derived from it, which states that $r+4$ uniform and random sample from $G$ is sufficient to generate $G$ with a probability of at least $1/2$. Or the sample is 'likely' to contain the basis for the lattice (group). As per the paper, the proof is as follows:

Proof: Otherwise, with probability at least 1/2, r+ 5 elements are needed to generate G. Since this random variable is never smaller than r by assumption, and its expectation is at least r + 5/2 > r + σ, in contradiction.

I need some help understanding the above-highlighted line.

This is just Markov's inequality that states that for a positive random variable $X$ and $a > 0$ then
$$
P( X \geq a ) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}. 
$$
see the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality.
Now, $a = 5$ and $X$ is the number of elements needed to generate the group minus $r$. Thus,
$$
\frac{5}{2} \leq E(X).
$$
If $Y$ is the random variables corresponding to the number of samples needed to generate the group, then
$X = Y-r$ and so
$$
\frac{5}{2} + r \leq E(Y). 
$$

a small clarification. Based on the last line of your answer, I see a lower bound on E(X) of 'r/2 +5/2'. We need to show a lower bound of 'r+5/2' (the highlighted line in the question). Perhaps I am missing something. Could you make it a bit more precise for me? Thanks!!

Good, point we need to use that $X \geq r$. Let me edit.
